# Save an object returned by a form to a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I save an object to a database after it is filled with data by a form?

These are my controller actions:

```
def new
  @product= Product.new
end

def create
  ......
  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

`params[:product]` is the object that I would like to save, something like:

```
params[:product].save
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this without creating a new product and setting its fields one by one like this:

```
def create
  @product= Product.new
  @product.category_id = params[:product][:category_id]
   ...
  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Also the redirect from the end doesn't seem to work, it says:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ProductsController#create
undefined method `product_url' for #<Admin::ProductsController:0x007fea5c8c86f8>
```

Comment: do you have `show` method? `def show @product=Product.find(params[:id]) end` and in `app/views/products/show.html.erb`

Comment: no, i don't have, because showing products is not a required functionality. I am trying to add a new record to the database.

Comment: you already have my vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple stuff, you can pass all of the params from your form into the new object in one go like so:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)

  if @product.save
    redirect_to products_url # Since you don't want to show the product, back to list
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def product_params 
  params.require(:product).permit(:category_id, ...) # Add any other attribute names from your form
end
```

If the save fails, it will then have an `errors` array that you can output on the `new` page.

I'd recommend you look at [scaffolds and generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) as they build all of this code for you.

Comment: already tried this and got: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: @LogofaT You need to use strong params, have added to my example.

Answer (score 1):

If you get `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`, you need to make use of strong parameters:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_parameters)
  # ...
end
# ...
private

def product_parameters
  params.require(:product).permit('list of permitted parameters')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter hash to `new` to set all the parameters at once. Something like this should work

```
def create
  @product= Product.new(params[:product])
  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, moslty because if you will do save with that matter, you will have a large hole (for hackers) in your site security. You must parse the `params` variable hash manually, or semi-automatically, cropping ids out of the params, and then find, create or update a record.

For example in your case you should do something like that:

```
class ProductsController
  before_filter :find_category, :only => [ :create ]

  def create
    @product= Product.new params
    @product.category = @category
    ...
    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private

  def find_category
    @category = Category.find_by_id params[:product][:category_id]
  end

end
```

Of course you shell to protect your search mechanizm from passing invalid ids into.